# Right-Aligning printed text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on printing a receipt right now, but I can't figure out how to right align text in graphics mode. I've tried a couple different things, but they're either really inefficient or don't work in my situation. Is there a way I can easily align text like to the right? Here's my code right now.

```
using (Font printFont = new Font("Courier New", 9.0f))
        {               
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Subtotal:", printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 80, HeightToPrint, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString(subtotal.ToString(), printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 150, HeightToPrint, new StringFormat());
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Graphics.MeasureString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) to get how long the rendered string will be and draw it at `rightMargin - measuredStringWidth`.

Comment: This will not work fine when part of text is left-to-right and another part is right-to-left (e.g. Arabic & English text in the same line). @Chris answer will work fine in that case

Answer (score 25):

In order for it to be able to right align the text, you need to specify a layout rectangle:

```
var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far };
var rect = new RectangleF( x, y, width, height );

e.Graphics.DrawString( text, font, brush, rect, format );
```

And it will then align the string within that rectangle.